# Laravel Homestead Intertia Vue Vite "npm run dev" Problem

Tags: laravel, vue.js, homestead, inertiajs

I am trying to run an Inertia Vue Laravel project with Homestead. But after installing breeze just like in the documentation and running the "npm run dev" command, the vue pages do not refresh when I made changes to the pages. So for example, when I edit the email title in Login page of Vue, it doesn't update. To add more confusion, when I check the vue dev tools, it says that the page is already a production page so the refs cannot be viewed. Maybe, this has something to do with how homestead work? I have no idea. What could be the root problem? And why are the assets on vite already in production when runnning through Homestead? This would make development really uneasy at this point.

Comment: when you say doesn't update, do you mean does not hot reload (need to manually refresh page) or does not really update even with refresh or cache clear refresh?

Comment: In your env file make sure you have APP_ENV=local

Comment: You are probably using [laravel vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite), so add the following to your `package.json`  `"watch": "vite build --watch"`, or just run `vite build --watch` to see if it gives you the results wanted.